# How to run Spring Boot Application at minimal requirement?

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, centos, microservices

I am using Spring Boot to build up my microservice architecture. As there would be many Spring Boot Application which would be more than 10 application.

However, I do not have enough resource to run all application in one single machine which is only just 1GB.

I simply run the application with the below command.

```
java -jar <application.jar>
```

If there are three application running in the same times, I found that each would consume 1/4 memory. It is impossible to run forth application.

How can I run more than four spring boot java application in a machine which is just around 1GB in the same times?

Comment: If limiting your resources is not an option or sufficient, your best bet is to switch to a more lightweight framework, e.g. [thorntail](https://thorntail.io/) or [quarkus](https://quarkus.io/). The latter allows (with the help of [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/)) AOT native compilation, which has a lower memory footrpint as one of its main goals.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like `java -Xmx256M -jar` for your jar to run on max 256MB.

More here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html

Comment: I have only 1gb for the machine. 256 *4 would use all the memory. The fourth one could not be started up.

Comment: Then try allocating less memory, 192 for example

Comment: dont use `-Xmx...`. Use `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` instead. See [this article](https://royvanrijn.com/blog/2018/05/java-and-docker-memory-limits/).

Comment: Cool article, I was not aware of that option. Just make sure your installed Java is 9+

Comment: I have used +Xmx for java option. My Os is centos. It seems that each java instance is using 1/4 of the total memory.

Comment: If the answer above was helpful feel free to mark it as useful.